# Creating sections with headers with two dynamic tableviewcells in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a table view with two cells, "electionInfo" and "candidates". Candidates returns an array of the candidates, while electionInfo gives a single text body (so just one cell). I'd like to divide them into two sections with their respective headers. Right now, it gives me one header for both cells. How do I fix it?

Thanks!!

My code...

```
@IBOutlet weak var table: UITableView!

    var info: [PFObject] = []
    var items: [PFObject] = []
    let titles = ["Election Info", "Candidates"]

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.items.count + 1
    }

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return self.items.count   
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        return titles[section]
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if indexPath.row == self.items.count {

            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("candidateCell") as! CandidateTableViewCell
            let candidate = items[indexPath.row]
            cell.candidateImage.file = candidate["image"] as! PFFile
            cell.candidateImage.loadInBackground()
            cell.candidateName?.text = candidate["name"] as! String
            cell.candidateParty?.text = candidate["partyAffiliation"] as! String

            return cell

    } else {

            let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("electionCell") as! ElectionInfoTableViewCell
            cell.electionInfo.text = "hey there"

        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
internal func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int     {

    return 2 //or the number of sections you have

}

internal func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

      let cell = UITableViewCell()

      if indexPath.section == 0 {

      let candidateCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("candidateCell") as! CandidateTableViewCell
      let candidate = items[indexPath.row]
      cell.candidateImage.file = candidate["image"] as! PFFile
      cell.candidateImage.loadInBackground()
      cell.candidateName?.text = candidate["name"] as! String
      cell.candidateParty?.text = candidate["partyAffiliation"] as! String

      return candidateCell

      } if indexPath.section == 1 {

      let electionCell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("electionCell") as! ElectionInfoTableViewCell
      cell.electionInfo.text = "hey there"

      return electionCell

     }

    return cell
}
```

then you have also to change your `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

    if section == 0 {

        return self.items.count 


    }
    if section == 1 {
         return self.items.count // or the number of rows you have in that section 


    }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

A section and a cell is different thing in tableview. Right now your code gives you section instead of cell because you return `self.items.count + 1` in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`. A fix for this;

Since your tableview should contain two section only you must return 2 or titles.count in `numberOfSectionsInTableView`

```
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

    return self.titles.count   
}
```

Next return corresponding array count in `numberOfRowsInSection`

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0{
        return self.info.count
    }else{
        return self.items.count
    }
}
```

And finally in cell for row at index path return cell based on a section:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {

        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("candidateCell") as! CandidateTableViewCell
        let candidate = items[indexPath.row]
        cell.candidateImage.file = candidate["image"] as! PFFile
        cell.candidateImage.loadInBackground()
        cell.candidateName?.text = candidate["name"] as! String
        cell.candidateParty?.text = candidate["partyAffiliation"] as! String

        return cell

} else {

        let cell = table.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("electionCell") as! ElectionInfoTableViewCell
        cell.electionInfo.text = "hey there"

    }
  }
```

Comment: This worked! I just had to change the the "if section == 0" to "if section == 2" in the number of rows section. It put everything in the right order with the right headers, though I'm not exactly sure why. I would have thought it would be 0 as well.

Comment: @BethKnight No thats not a correct approach it must be `if section == 0` otherwise it will skip the first section always!!!